Force specific WooCommerce product OR product variation to be sold in separately
I have this code, below, care of Force specific WooCommerce product to be sold in separate order and User 7uc1f3r.
I wish to add two other products to this code. The first product is simple, the other two are variable. These products have weight variations and I only want one of the weight variations to trigger the script and prevent addition to the cart with other products. So, the code would cycle through an array of product IDs, as below:
function filter_woocommerce_add_product_to_cart_array_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variations ) {
    
    // Product id to bought alone 
    $product_id_alone_array = array("1562", "1619");
    // Product id of the variation to be bought alone 
    $variation_id_alone_array = array("1319", "1476");

    // Set variable
    $flag = false;

    // cycle through the array 'product_id_alone_array'
    foreach ($product_id_alone_array as $product_id_alone) {
        // If cart is NOT empty when a product is added
       if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            // Generate a unique ID for the cart item
            $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id_alone );

            // Check if product is in the cart
            $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

            // If product is already in cart & product ID added is not equal to product ID alone
            if ( $in_cart && ( $product_id != $product_id_alone ) ) {
                $flag = true;
            // Product ID alone is NOT in cart & product ID added is equal to product ID alone
            } elseif( ! $in_cart && ( $product_id == $product_id_alone ) ) {
                $flag = true;
            }
        }

        global $product;
        // If the WC_product Object is not defined globally
        if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        }
        $product_name = $product->get_name();

        // True
        if ( $flag ) {
            // Set error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                __( 'Product <b>%s</b> must be bought separately due to our shipping arrangements.', 'woocommerce' ),
                $product_name,
            ), 'error' );

            // Passed = false
            $passed = false;
        }

        return $passed;
    }

    // cycle through the array 'variation_id_alone_array'
    foreach ($variation_id_alone_array as $variation_id_alone) {
        
        //$variations = $variation_id_alone->get_available_variations();
        //$variations_id = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'variation_id' );
        //print_r('Variations: '.$variations_id, TRUE);
        
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id_alone );
        $variation_data = $_product->get_variation_attributes();
        //$variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, true );  // this will give all variation detail in one line
        $variation_detail = woocommerce_get_formatted_variation( $variation_data, false);  // this will give all variation detail one by one
        return $variation_detail; // $variation_detail will return string containing variation detail which can be used to print on website
        return $variation_data; // $variation_data will return only the data which can be used to store variation data
        
        // If cart is NOT empty when a variation is added
       if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            // Generate a unique ID for the cart item
            $variation_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $variation_id_alone );

            // Check if variation is in the cart
            $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $variation_cart_id );

            // If variation is already in cart & variation ID added is not equal to variation ID alone
            if ( $in_cart && ( $variation_id != $variation_id_alone ) ) {
                $flag = true;
            // Variation ID alone is NOT in cart & variation ID added is equal to variation ID alone
            } elseif( ! $in_cart && ( $variation_id == $variation_id_alone ) ) {
                $flag = true;
            }
        }

        global $product;
        // If the WC_product Object is not defined globally
        if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
        }
        $product_name = $product->get_name();

        // True
        if ( $flag ) {
            // Set error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                __( 'Product <b>%s</b> must be bought separately due to our shipping arrangements.', 'woocommerce' ),
                $product_name,
            ), 'error' );

            // Passed = false
            $passed = false;
        }

        return $passed;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation_', 'filter_woocommerce_add_product_to_cart_array_validation', 10, 5 );


@LoicTheAztec, Appreciate your input. I've updated the code to include the variations code. Look forward to your assistance.

There are some mistakes, complications and the code can really be simplified and optimized.
As your targeted products need to be sold separately, the cart should be always empty, so there is no need to check if any of those products are in cart.
There is no need to separate defined products IDs and product variations IDS.
Try the following validation function :
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_products_to_be_sold_separately', 10, 4 );
function filter_products_to_be_sold_separately( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id ) {
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        return $passed; // Exit if cart is empty
    }
    // HERE, define the targeted products OR product variations IDs to be sold separately
    $targeted_ids = array(1562, 1619, 1319, 1476);

    if ( ! array_intersect($targeted_ids, [$product_id, $variation_id]) ) {
        return $passed; // Exit if it's not a targeted product
    }
    // Get the product or product variation object
    $product = wc_get_product( $variation_id ?: $product_id ); 

    // Displays an error message
    wc_add_notice( sprintf(
        __( 'Product <b>%s</b> must be bought separately due to our shipping arrangements.', 'woocommerce' ),
        $product->get_formatted_name(),
    ), 'error' );

    return false;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
